# ionic app running on Nougat but fails on KitKat

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, deployment

I've developed an ionic 1 application which runs flawlesly on my Galaxy S7 (7.0.0 - API level 24), but when I'm trying to run the same app on KitKat device (4.4.2 API level 19) I'm getting the white screen of death.

By default, ionic-cordova defines

> Android target: android-26

As you can see here:

[image]

After spending a few hours on browsing the internet, first, I thought, I would be able to solve the problem by playing with configuration files (config.xml, build.json, AndroidManifest.xml) and changing android target number to 19 but it didn't help.

I'm an angular (web) developer, so I don't have any expirience with androind development, so may be I'm just don't tunderstand right how the things work.

PS: I'm using latest ionic, ionic cli and cordova versions.
PSS: I have made my development on blank ionic project without any additional plugins except this plugin:

> phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. To make the app running on the KitKat devices I was needed to add the following plugin:

> [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)